# SwiftUi create function with array as parameter and also array type of element

Tags: arrays, function, swiftui, parameters, element

I'm looking to do a function which take all the information of one Element of my structured array. And as I would like to do it on many array (of same Type) and many elements of this array I'd like to do a single function which take in parameter the array's name and the Array's element where I would like to work.

My array exemple :

```
class FlightLibrary: ObservableObject{

    @Published var testFlight = [
        Flight(seTime: "00:20", meTime: "", nightTime: "", ifrTime: "", captainTime: "00:20", copilotTime: "", dualTime: ""),
        Flight(seTime: "00:40", meTime: "00:20", nightTime: "", ifrTime: "", captainTime: "00:20", copilotTime: "", dualTime: ""),
        Flight(seTime: "00:35", meTime: "", nightTime: "00:20", ifrTime: "", captainTime: "00:20", copilotTime: "", dualTime: "")
        
    ]
}
```

And my attempt for my function :

```
func GetSpecificTotalTime(inArray: Array<Flight>, ofTime: Array<Flight>.Element) -> String{

    var specificTotalTime: String = ""
    var specificTimeInt: Int = 0
    
    for i in inArray{
        let stringValueToAdd: String = i.oftime
    }
    
    return specificTotalTime
}
```

Here I've my function where, for exemple, I'd like to work in my array `testFlight` on the element `.seTime`. So I would have something like :

```
GetSpecificTotalTime(inArray: testFlight, ofTime: seTime)
```

But in my function the line `let stringValueToAdd: String = i.oftime` didn't work.
Here I want to fil `stringValueToAdd` by the value which is on `enteredArray[i].enteredElement` and after work with this value before going to the next index.

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter is not an array. `Array<Flight>.Element` is just a `Flight`.

A possible way is to specify a key path as second parameter for example

```
func getSpecificTotalTime(inArray: Array<Flight>, ofTime: KeyPath<Flight,String>) -> String {
```

Then you can get any string property with

```
for i in inArray{
    let stringValueToAdd: String = i[keyPath: ofTime]
}
```

and call it

```
getSpecificTotalTime(inArray: testFlight, ofTime: \.seTime)
```